# Adding a cookie to web service port client

Tags: c#, web-services, client, cookies, cookiecontainer

I'm using a web service in my app that requires a specific cookie to be set in order access it's methods.

I was using a generated wrapper class for that service that was created using `wsdl.exe` tool. Everything is working ok using that method.

```
// this is the instance of object generated with wsdl.exe
WSWrapper service = new WSWrapper(); 

// set cookie
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();    
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value, path, domain);
service.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);

// run method requiring cookie to be set
service.Test();
```

Now I wanted to do something similar using Service Reference instead of pre-generated class. I added web reference but there seems to be no `CookieContainer` (or anything similar) in service reference port client that was generated.

Does anyone knows how to add a cookie to that client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of creating Service Reference I added Web Reference and the generated client had all the properties of the `wsdl.exe` pre-generated class.

Answer (score 4):

There are advantages to the `svcutil.exe` generated proxies though.

Having the client save and return the cookies returned by the server (as used to be done by simply adding a `CookieContainer`) can now be controlled through app.config. Add `allowCookies="true`" to the `basicHttpBinding` or `basicHttpsBinding` as an attribute to the binding.

Alternatively use the WCF configuration editor to do the same.